# open new activity everytime an item is clicked in child list

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Hi I'm really new in this. I have the code for an expandable listview. when clicked on the child items, it simply display a toast of the same text. I want to open a new activity when we click on any child item. Any help will be much appreciated.

```css
MyExpandableAdapter

public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{
 
  private Activity activity;
     private ArrayList<Object> childtems;
     private LayoutInflater inflater;
     private ArrayList<String> parentItems, child;

     // constructor
     public MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents, ArrayList<Object> childern)
     {
         this.parentItems = parents;
         this.childtems = childern;
     }

     public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity) 
     {
         this.inflater = inflater;
         this.activity = activity;
     }
     
     // method getChildView is called automatically for each child view.
     //  Implement this method as per your requirement
     @Override
     public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
     {

         child = (ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition);

         TextView textView = null;

         if (convertView == null) {
             convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, null);
         }
     
          // get the textView reference and set the value
         textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChild);
         textView.setText(child.get(childPosition));

         // set the ClickListener to handle the click event on child item
         convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                 Toast.makeText(activity, child.get(childPosition),
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
         });
         return convertView;
     }

     // method getGroupView is called automatically for each parent item
     // Implement this method as per your requirement
     @Override
     public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
     {

         if (convertView == null) {
             convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_view, null);
         }

         ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));
         ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);

         return convertView;
     }

     @Override
     public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
     {
         return null;
     }

     @Override
     public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
     {
         return 0;
     }

     @Override
     public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) 
     {
         return ((ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition)).size();
     }

     @Override
     public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) 
     {
         return null;
     }

     @Override
     public int getGroupCount() 
     {
         return parentItems.size();
     }

     @Override
     public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) 
     {
         super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
     }

     @Override
     public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition)
     {
         super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
     }

     @Override
     public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) 
     {
         return 0;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean hasStableIds() 
     {
         return false;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
     {
         return false;
     }

}
```

```html
Main Activity

public class MainActivity extends ExpandableListActivity{
 
 // Create ArrayList to hold parent Items and Child Items
    private ArrayList<String> parentItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Object> childItems = new ArrayList<Object>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        
        // Create Expandable List and set it's properties
        ExpandableListView expandableList = getExpandableListView(); 
        expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
        expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
        expandableList.setClickable(true);

        // Set the Items of Parent
        setGroupParents();
        // Set The Child Data
        setChildData();

        // Create the Adapter
        MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(parentItems, childItems);

        adapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);
        
        // Set the Adapter to expandableList
        expandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
        expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(this);
    }

    // method to add parent Items
    public void setGroupParents() 
    {
        parentItems.add("Company");
        parentItems.add("Pricing & Plans");
        parentItems.add("Services");
        parentItems.add("Careers");
        parentItems.add("Clients");
        parentItems.add("Contact Us");
    }

    // method to set child data of each parent
    public void setChildData() 
    {

        // Add Child Items for Company
        ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Who We Are");
        child.add("Advantage @ KDIPL");
        child.add("Team");
       
        
        childItems.add(child);

        // Add Child Items for Pricing & Plans
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("SEO Packages");
        child.add("SMO Packages");
        child.add("PPC Packages");
        child.add("Web Design Packages");
        child.add("Web Development Packages");
        child.add("Email Marketing Packages");
        child.add("Bulk SMS Packages");
        
        childItems.add(child);

        // Add Child Items for Services
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
       
        child.add("SMO Services");
        child.add("PPC Services");
        child.add("Web Design Services");
        child.add("Web Development Services");
        child.add("SEO Services");
        
        childItems.add(child);

        // Add Child Items for Careers
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Career with Us");
        child.add("Current Openings");
        child.add("Recruitment Process");
        
        childItems.add(child);
        
     // Add Child Items for Clients
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Testimonials");
        child.add("SEO Results");
        child.add("PPC Results");
        child.add("Portfolio");
        
        childItems.add(child);
        
     // Add Child Items for Contact Us
        child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Location");
        child.add("Request a Quote");
        child.add("Feedback");
        
        childItems.add(child);
        
        
    }
    
    
 
 
}
```

Comment: read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent) to lean how to start a new activity

Comment: did your problem got resolve?

Answer (score 0):

**You can write this**

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   Intent intent= new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                   context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

**Instead of this**

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, child.get(childPosition),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

**And make one constructor in your adapter like this**

```
private Context context;
public MyExpandableAdapter (Context context) {
              this.context = context;     
         }
```

Comment: will this open a new activity for every child items?

Answer (score 0):

In you activity add this

```
           // Listview on child click listener
            expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),groupPosition+ " group "+childPosition+" is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                    Intent in = new Intent(Class_Name.this, JUMP_Class.class);
                    startActivity(in);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```